# Why is expo-create-app taking way too long?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npx, yarn-v2

I've left both the following commands overnight and neither worked (they paused after I entered the name for the project, despite still using resources in task manager)

```
PS C:\Users\2025a\Documents\Code> npx create-expo-app --template
√ Choose a template: » Navigation (TypeScript)
√ What is your app named? ... my-app
```

```
PS C:\Users\2025a\Documents\Code> yarn create expo-app --template
yarn create v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-expo-app@2.1.1" with binaries:
      - create-expo-app
√ Choose a template: » Navigation (TypeScript)
√ What is your app named? ... my-app
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? I've already reinstalled create-expo-app and repaired npm